# Upload file on the response of first upload file

Tags: java, android, post, file-upload, image-uploading

What I want to do it so upload multiple files (in java), I know how to upload single file or multiple files in a single request but what I require is a bit different.

I just want to upload a file and on the response of upload the second file. How can I achieve this? I have all the paths stored in Arraylist. Is there any library or easy way to do this?

I want to make this thing generic.

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: As soon as the response is 'in' start uploading the next.

Comment: Then I will have to keep record of counters and I dont want to get into that mess, since the structure is somewhat like this 
multiple cases--- multiple media files in each case

Comment: Well I don't know what you want to say with those 'cases'. But if you have all paths stored in an array list then you can just loop through the array list and upload one after the other. If you can upload one file then you can upload more in a loop. Just add three lines of code. Thats all.

Comment: I have to use to response after uploading as well. So the way you are suggesting isnt very useful for me. Because uploading is a asynchronous call. I guess I will use the counters way. 
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Of course uploading is an asynchronous call. That does not matter. You realise that if you don't tell the basic things about how you implemented uploading that a discussion about your problem is difficult?